# how to create a +1 on a link to a notifications page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a page that allows a **company** to view a **users** **answer** to an **application**.

If the user have created an application, and a user has answered it, it will show up on the page. Displaying their answer, who answered it and what time they answered it.

What I would like to do is add a notification system on the link to this page so that it is possible for the company to know when a new user has answered their application, without having to be / visit the page.

The page is straight forward.

**companies_controller:**

```
def applicants
 @applications = current_company.applications.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

**applicants.html.erb:**

```
<% @applications.all.each do |application| %>
<% application.answers.each do |answer| %>

  <p>Your question1: <%= answer.application.question_1 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 1: <%= answer.answer_1 %></p>
  <p>Your question 2: <%= answer.application.question_2 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_2 %></p>
  <p>Your question 3: <%= answer.application.question_3 %></p>
  <p>Their answer 3: <%= answer.answer_3 %></p>


  <i>Answered by <b><%= link_to "#{answer.user.fullname}", user_path(answer.user.slug) %></b>, <%= time_ago_in_words(answer.created_at) %> ago</i> | <%= button_to "delete this applicant", root_url, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, method: :delete %>
  <hr>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Each company when signed in have the ability to visit the applicants page through their navigation in the header. Ideally I'd want a counter (1,2,3) next to it for example. Depending on the amount of new users that have applied. How can I create this?

Comment: You want counter on which? on the question?

Comment: @Pavan yes if a new answer to a question (that belongs to the current_company) have been created

Comment: `counter_cache` could be the solution for you,but i'm confused how to apply it on your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Live**

From my understanding here (you want a stateless piece of functionality which updates notifications after they are made)?

If so, I would recommend looking into `websockets` / `live` functionality. This basically allows you to show different triggers when your application acts in a particular way. IE you want to use `push notifications` or similar

---

**JS**

There are a number of ways to achieve this, all using the same pattern - use JS on the front-end to *"listen"* for any updates from the server.

The server will then send the updates asynchronously (using something such as `websockets`, `SSE`'s  or similar). One the message has been sent, the JS "listener" will essentially "catch" the message & follwo your functionality to process it.

A good example is [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/):

```
source = new EventSource('your/endpoint');
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

This is covered using the [`ActionController::Live`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) functionality in Rails, but is much better handled by a third party at the moment (sad but true)

--

**Events**

There are several things for you to look at:

**[SSE's (Server Sent Events)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)**

Server Sent Events are a HTML5 feature, basically allowing you to send asynchronous messages from the server to your front-end:

> A server-sent event is when a web page automatically gets updates from
>   a server.
>
> This was also possible before, but the web page would have to ask if
>   any updates were available. With server-sent events, the updates come
>   automatically.
>
> Examples: Facebook/Twitter updates, stock price updates, news feeds,
>   sport results, etc.

This is not through Ajax - it's through HTTP with JS, and is handled using the `text/event-stream` header. You'd handle it like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :your_controller do
    collection do
       get :messages #-> domain.com/your_controller/messages
    end
end
```

If you set JS to "listen" to that URL, you'll be able to "catch" any information you send from the server, like this:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def message
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new(response.stream, retry: 300, event: "event-name")
    sse.write({ name: 'John'})
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10)
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10, event: "other-event")
    sse.write({ name: 'John'}, id: 10, event: "other-event", retry: 500)
  ensure
    sse.close
  end
end
```

This will allow you to use the javascript like this:

```
var source = new EventSource("/your_controller/messages");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
    alert ("message");
};
```

--

[**Websockets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Although the SSE route is "native" to HTML5 (except for IE), it's basically a glorified version of [Ajax Long-Polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), basically meaning your browser is going to be pinging your server every second for updates. LAME

A much more robust way is to use `websockets`, which essentially creates a perpetual connection between your browser & the server. Although we've not got this working natively in Rails yet, we *have* found a system called [**Pusher**](http://pusher.com) which can handle it

Pusher is a plugin which basically creates a `websocket` through their servers. This means you can include their [`gem`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem), allowing you to converse with your front-end (in a much similar way to Redis):

```
#app/controllers/my_controller.rb
Class MyController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
      Pusher.trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', {
          message: 'hello world'
      });
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
  alert('Received my-event with message: ' + data.message);
});
```